# Could I send data of DHT11 on ESP8266 to my RPi3?

Tags: esp8266

Maybe my question is little weird.

1. Using rpi3, node mcu, dht11(or another sensor)
2. get a data of dht11 on nodemcu
3. want this data to rpi3

is it realizable??

Comment: yes this is possible. you should be able to find tutorials on the web using e.g. the MQTT protocol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Question***

> Maybe my question is little weird
>
> Using rpi3, node mcu, dht11 (or another sensor)
>
> get a data of dht11 on nodemcu
>
> want this data to rpi3
>
> is it realizable??

***Answer***

Ah, your question is not weird all, just a very common Rpi (python) NodeMcu (Lua) newbie programming exercise.

I would recommend to use the very simple UART method (not so complicated as MQTT, which of course you should try later).  With real physical wires TX, Rx human can touch (and can use LED to display status, if no scope available), newbies should not find things so scary and easy to troubleshoot.  Furthermore you can complete the complicated thing in three steps.

> 1. Separately check that Rpi, Esp8266 can themselves loop back (just connecting local Tx to Rx to form a loop, no external connection)
> 2. Use a terminal emulator such Win10 puTTY/Superterm, or Rpi puTTY to talk to separately talk to Rpi or Esp8266 (eg, puTTY say "AT/r/n",
>      Rpi or Esp should reply "OK/r/n".
> 3. Of course if you have arduino/Rpi UART experience, you can skip Step 2, and just use a Lua snippet with command uart.write() to write
>      a string to UART and Rpi to read the string on the other side.

NodeMcu has good documention for this basic things, but there are many traps, each of which would waste hours.  So it is a good idea to carefully a couple of times.  For example, NodeMcu UART0 can read and write, but ***UART1 can read only***.  The other trouble maker is baud rate.  Some modules default to 115,200bps, but some starts with 9,600 baud.  This kind of inconsistency across vendors and version also waste much newbies' time.

I have summarized the essential documentation in the reference section below for your easy reference, in case you miss something basic.

Good luck and have a nice project!

***References***

[NodeMcu Open Source Lua Based Firmware and Development Kit Introduction](https://www.nodemcu.com/index_en.html)

[NodMcu Official Documentation](https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/master/)

[NodeMcu Lua DHT11 Module](https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/master/modules/dht/)

[NodeMcu C UART Module](https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/master/modules/uart/)

[NodeMcu Lua Set UART Bit Rate](https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/master/build/#set-uart-bit-rate)

[NodeMcu UART Write - uart.write() Write string or byte to the UART.](https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/master/modules/uart/)

Comment: First of all, Tkank you for your relpy and answer. I have some question... I never know about lua but know about python. So I am trying to using micropython on nodemcu. Also Can I handle it?? Again really Thank you :)

Comment: Yes, go ahead.  What are your questions?

Comment: Oh my goodness.  That is a big problem.  Let me update my answer later, perhaps this afternoon.  There is a confusion.  I think micropython has nothing to do with NodeMcu.  It runs REPL on itself.

Comment: hmm.. I know that micropython can mount on nodemcu board.. Isn't it???

Comment: Well, not exactly.  The "board" should be called ESP8266 01/02 ...12/32 board.  You can run Lua or microPython.  If you run Lua, you must use NodeMcu firmware, not much choice.  But if you run microPython, you can say use editor Mu to write your micropython program and uploaded it to the harware board.  A not very good analogy is Rpi can load linux OS or Risc OS or WinIoT, ... When you run WinIoT things, it has little to do with linux/Raspbian, ...

Comment: How about learning lua ?? instead using micropython??

Comment: I mean which one is more easy for me ㅠㅠ   learning lua(refer github) or using micropython

Comment: Ah, this is a difficult question.  Lua is at least 5 times harder to learn than micropython.  But Lua is 5 times easier to program for event driven applications.

Comment: Oh yes.. this is very weird question.. sry..Anyway, you are so kind :) Thank you

Comment: Ah, this is a difficult question.  L is at least 5 times harder to learn than MP.  But L is 5 times easier to program for event driven applications.  If your short term goal is to complete a programming assignment for your teacher, go MP.  But if you wish to long term do WiFi, IoT things, then L.  No pain no gain.  If you wish to earn more money later, then L now, because you learn many useful things other don't know, ... :).  But of course it also depends on your IQ.  If in school, you always rank top 10 percent of class, and you are good at chess Go etc, then go Lua, otherwise, forget it.

Comment: Go is goole Go language right?? And I also electronic engineering in university.. But there is no time to learn about python or Lua  ㅠㅠ Although my poor Enlish conversion skill, you catch my thing very well  Challenge learn Lua gogogogogo!!

Comment: great... No I have no time to learn that.I focus on my lecture with hardware.. Nowdays I just play with rpi3 for fun :)

Comment: Ah, I agree you should focus on lectures and hardware first.  If you got addicted to software, which is somewhat like video games, there is a risk that you would not have enough time left to study and fail the exam. And if Rpi hardware is part of your homework assignment/lab work, then you have already more than enough fun!

Comment: Yeah maybe, you are right. Actually iam a newbie of rpi. I am gonna first do this project which written on questions. First, ust follow the manual. I really hope it will work : )